# How to split data from one column in several lines

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, list

I have a table with one reference column and one column with multiples data. I want to create lines for every data in the second column. It's separated by a comma, like this :

```
[a] [1,2,3]
[b] [4,5,6]
[c] [7,8,9]
```

And i want to create this :

```
[a] [1]
[b] [2]
[c] [3]
[d] [4]
[e] [5]
[f] [6]
[g] [7]
[h] [8]
[i] [9]
```

I don't know how to start this for the moment

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show the actual code. I'm not sure what types are these things :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what form your 'table' is in nor where [a] involves a variable `a` or the letter 'a'. On the basis that this is pandas dataframe then you can use `.explode` and reform the first column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
                    "col1": ['a', 'b', 'c'],
                    "col2" : [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5,6],[7, 8, 9]]
                   })
print(df)

df = df.explode('col2').reset_index(drop=True)

df['col1'] = df.index.map(lambda x: chr(ord('a')+x))

print(df)
```

which gives:

```
  col1       col2
0    a  [1, 2, 3]
1    b  [4, 5, 6]
2    c  [7, 8, 9]
  col1 col2
0    a    1
1    b    2
2    c    3
3    d    4
4    e    5
5    f    6
6    g    7
7    h    8
8    i    9
```